# How we can define Super-Greedy Linear extension of a Poset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I am trying to understand the Super-Greedy linear extension of a poset. It is a topic of discrete mathematics, and I have tried to search the web, but only got one useful definition which I can't comprehend completely. I will attach the definition here, it would be a great help if anyone can help me to understand it:
[Supergreedy Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwnKy.png).

If someone wants to dig into it, [here](https://trotter.math.gatech.edu/papers/66.pdf) is the complete paper.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please define the algorithm yourself and explain the context, say what it is used for? Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a relation $<:$ involved; what is the definition of that?

Comment: I myself didn't understand the algorithm, I need to understand this so as to implement it.

Comment: I myself didn't get that completely, I assumed that might be denoting a less than inequality whereas both the elements corresponds to particular set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a better reference is https://trotter.math.gatech.edu/papers/60.pdf (the paper which introduced the notion of supergreedy extension):

A linear extension $[x_1<x_2<...<x_t]$ of a finite ordered set $P=(P, <)$ is super greedy if it can be obtained using the following procedure: Choose $x_1$ to be a minimal element of $P$; suppose $x_1,...,x_i$ have been chosen; define $p(x)$ to be the largest $j\leq i$ such that $x_j<x$ if such a $j$ exists and $0$ otherwise; choose $x_{i+1}$ to be a minimal element of
$P-\{x_1,...,x_i\}$ which maximizes $p$.